# React App, Using Font Awesome brand icons in React VS Vue

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, font-awesome

I am trying to use the brand icons from Font Awesome, I have already used it before in a vue application, it's a little different from using the regular svg icons as the brands library is separate from the regular solid svg icons. this is how i used in a vue app.

```js
// imports in the main.js file
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

library.add(faCoffee, faFacebookF);

Vue.component('fa-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)

// usage in a vue component - regular svg icons 
<fa-icon icon="coffee" />
// brand icon 
<fa-icon class="ic right" :icon="['fab', 'facebook-f']" />
```

Now i am trying to do a similar thing in a react app, But I am a little stuck on where and how to import and use it, In Vue, I defined the `<fa-icon />` globally in my `main.js`, but things are a little different with React. here is my attempt in a react component.

```js
// imports in my app.js file 
import React from 'react';

import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

library.add(faCoffee, faFacebookF)
//this works 
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" />
//this does not
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={"['fab', 'facebook-f']"} />
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'facebook-f']} />
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome#build-a-library-to-reference-icons-throughout-your-app-more-conveniently

Answer (score 0):

**Install**   All Free Font Awesome Icons-- Using cmd on your project location:

```
 npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
 npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
 npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
 npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
 npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
```

Import this for Font Awesome:

```
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
```

Add Font Awesome to your JSX:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF}></FontAwesomeIcon>
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter}/>
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle}/>
```

And Lastly, import your brands-icon from your installed repository:

```
import {faFacebookF, faGoogle, faTwitter} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
```